# URL GET values not being checked in checkbox

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I have a search form with method="POST". The user can also search via url, for example:

myurl.php?use_url=on&zipcode=London&categories=Firewood, Pellets

at the top of my page I have the following code to convert GET to POST:

```
$_POST['zipcode'] = addslashes($_GET['zipcode']);
$_POST['categories'] = addslashes($_GET['categories']);
$_POST['radius'] = addslashes($_GET['radius']);
```

I'm able to echo the zipcode value into my text field with the following code:

```
<input type="text" name="zipcode" value="<?php echo $_POST['zipcode']; ?>" />
```

I'm also able to echo the radius value into my select box with the following code:

```
<select name="radius" id="country_id" class="chosen-radius">
<?php 
    $radius_array = explode(",", get_setting('radius', $db));

    foreach ($radius_array AS $radius) {
?>
    <option <?php if($radius == $_POST['radius']) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="<?php echo $radius; ?>"><?php echo "Within&nbsp;" . $radius . "&nbsp;miles"; ?></option>
<?php 
    }
?>
</select>
```

the problem I'm having is echoing the categories value(s) from the URL into the checkboxes. Submitting the form via POST works fine, it's just via GET that the issue arises. Here's the code for the checkbox, as you can see I'm dealing with an array here:

```
<?php
$categories_list = explode("\n", get_setting('categories', $db));

foreach($categories_list as $cat) {
    $cat = trim($cat);

    // We've added the next line so category choices are remembered upon submit.
    if(isset($_POST['categories']) 
    && in_array($cat, $_POST['categories'])) { 
       $select = "CHECKED"; 
    } else { 
       $select = ''; 
    }

     echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" " . $select . " name=\"categories[]\" value=\"" . $cat . "\" /><label for=\"" . $cat . "\" class=\"css-label\">" . $cat . "</label><br>";
} 
?>
```

Can any kind person tell me why I can't echo the category values from the URL back into the checkboxes as "CHECKED"?

Comment: What is `$select`? Where does it add the `checked` attribute?

Comment: `$select` adds the `checked` attribute into the checkbox field, between type and name

Comment: According to your example, `$_GET['categories']` is in fact `Firewood, Pellets` (I'm guessing the space is a typing error?). You have to turn that into an array (`$categories = explode(',', $_GET['categories']);`) Then you can search that using `in_array()`. And there is no practical reason to "convert GET to POST".

Comment: Worked wonderfully Jared, a massive thank you! These things are always so obvious when explained. I'll look into a way of merging GET to POST, thanks for the tip!

Comment: You don't need to "merge GET to POST". Why do you think you need to? If you're really hot to access only one array, you can use `$_REQUEST`, which is a combination of both, but that is generally discouraged since any key in both can mean one gets stepped on.

Comment: As Jared mentioned, no need to convert/merge/etc GET vars to POST vars. A variable is a variable. This will work just as well: `$cats = explode(",", $_GET["categories"]);` Now, you have an array called `$cats`, and the value of `$cats[0]` will be `Firewood`

Comment: I simply assumed that the POST commands can't read GET vars, but this makes so much sense I feel like a plonker. One very big lesson learnt, thanks guys!!!